# SQL BETWEEN Operator in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_date 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

**How can I write this query in Laravel?**

Answer (score 2):

Laravel have a good solution for this and it is `whereBetween` see that here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

$now = Carbon::now();
$prev = Carbon::now()->subDays(90);

DB::table('mytable')->where(function ($query) use ($now,$prev) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_date', [$prev, $now]);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives you records that has date between now and date 90 days back:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d'); // now
$old = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-90 days')); // 90 days back
$records = DB::table('mytable')->where('created_date', '>=', $old)
                       ->where('created_date', '<=', $now)
                       ->get();
```

You should read Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

Hope it helps.